# How to use Array of C language with Objective-C

Tags: iphone, c, objective-c, arrays

I'm using Objective-C language. But I don't know how to use c with Objective-C.

Ex) This is Function method.

```
- ( ?? ) function{
unsigned int first = ..
unsigned int second = ..
unsigned int third = ..

int infoData = {first,second,third};
return infoData;
}
```

How to fill in parenthesis.

I don't use NSArray.

Please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you declared `int[] infoData` you could make the return `int*`, but you're still going to have problems because the array is allocated on the function's stack. You'll need to dynamically allocate space for it just like you would in C.

(You cannot use `int[]` as a return type)

The code below will compile, but gcc will warn about returning the address of a function local variable.

```
@interface test
- (int*) function;
@end

@implementation test

- (int*) function{
  unsigned int first = 0;
  unsigned int second = 1;
  unsigned int third = 2;

  int infoData[] = {first,second,third};
  return infoData;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 4):

the answer is the same as it is in C. Objective-C is a strict superset of C.